# Can I add days to the date merge tag in MailChimp?

Tags: date, merge, tags, mailchimp

For the automated "Final welcome email" (gets sent to subscriber after they sign up), I want to include a coupon that is good for 1 week. So, I'm trying to put an expiration date in the Welcome email. I would like to get the current date and add 7 days to it. I know for the current date you can do `*|DATE:m/d/y|*` but how can I add 7 days? Is it possible?

I tried the following, but they didn't get parsed :(

```
*|(DATE:m/d/y)+1|*
*|DATE:m/d/y+1|*
```

Thanks!
Heather

Comment: Did you managed to make this work?

Comment: No :( I ended up writing "Good for one week from *|DATE:m/d/y|*"

Comment: I see. thats smart :-)
But sadly no options to find, I tried with different combinations of php time. 
Last option to add a custom merge tag "Display Date" and re-import CSV with the field before sending to a set of clients.